# How can I group a continuous column (0-1) into equal sizes? Scala spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, binning

I have a dataframe column that I want to split into equal size buckets. The values in this column are floats between 0-1. Most of the data is skewed, so most values fall in the 0.90's and 1.

Bucket 10: All 1's (the size of this bucket will be different from 2-9 and 1)
Bucket 2-9: Any values > 0 and < 1 (equal sized)
Bucket 1: All 0's (the size of this bucket will be different from 2-9 and 10)

Example:

| continous_number_col | Bucket |
| --- | --- |
| 0.001 | 2 |
| 0.95 | 9 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 0 | 1 |

This should be how it looks when I groupBy("Bucket")
Counts of bucket 1 and 10 aren't significant here, they will just be in their own bucket.
And the 75 count will be different, just using as an example.

| Bucket | Count | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2 | 75 | 0.01 - 0.50 |
| 3 | 75 | 0.51 - 0.63 |
| 4 | 75 | 0.64 - 0.71 |
| 5 | 75 | 0.72 - 0.83 |
| 6 | 75 | 0.84 - 0.89 |
| 7 | 75 | 0.90 - 0.92 |
| 8 | 75 | 0.93 - 0.95 |
| 9 | 75 | 0.95 - 0.99 |
| 10 | 2000 | 1 |

I've tried using the QuantileDiscretizer() Function as this:

```
val df = {
 rawDf
  //Taking 1's and 0's out for the moment
  .filter(col("continuous_number_col") =!= 1 && col("continuous_number_col") =!= 0)       
}

val discretizer = new QuantileDiscretizer()
  .setInputCol("continuous_number_col")
  .setOutputCol("bucket_result")
  .setNumBuckets(8)

val result = discretizer.fit(df).transform(df)
```

However, this gives me the following, not equal buckets:

| bucket_result | count |
| --- | --- |
| 7.0 | 20845806 |
| 6.0 | 21096698 |
| 5.0 | 21538813 |
| 4.0 | 21222511 |
| 3.0 | 21193393 |
| 2.0 | 21413413 |
| 1.0 | 21032666 |
| 0.0 | 21681424 |

Hopefully this gives enough context to what I'm trying to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your attempt so far ? you have any code that failed  ?

Comment: Hi there, I just updated with my attempt on this. I included the code and output I got. Thanks for commenting